# The target "GetSolutionConfigurationContents" does not exist in the project

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, winjs

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution that includes a Windows 8.1 WinJS app along with a MVC web application.  When we build the solution locally in Visual Studio, it works fine, but building it on the build server fails with the following error:

"The target "GetSolutionConfigurationContents" does not exist in the project."

Could it be a software versioning issue between the local environment and what is installed on the build server? Any ideas would be helpful tracking this down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the package.appxmanifest file.

Under the Packaging tab, I had set the "Generate app bundle" option to "Always".

Setting it to "If needed" fixed the issue and the builds are now successful.

UPDATE:
The problem reoccurred when we targeted x64 builds only, so we had to keep this project setting:

```
<AppxBundlePlatforms>neutral</AppxBundlePlatforms>
```